# OpenOffice Calc: Finding max value

Tags: openoffice-calc

Let's say that i have an array:

```
   |A  B  C  D
---------------
1  |2  8  6  3
2  |1  2  5  2
```

Where first row stand for "Goals Scored" and the second row for "Goals Lost". Columns stands for games/matches

I want to find the maximum total number of goals scored and lost in one match. In case above it would be 11 (C1 + C2).

I don't want to use

I spent few days trying functions like: MAX, ADDRESS, CELL, SUBTOTAL, SUM, MMULT, TRANSPOSE, etc. and even combined but i didn't get satisfying result.

Answer (score 0):

The [MAX function](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_MAX_function) have to work:

> Returns the maximum of a list of arguments, ignoring text entries.
>
> Example:
>
> MAX(B1:B3)
>
> ```
> where cells B1, B2, B3 contain 1.1, 2.2, and apple returns 2.2.
> ```

Comment: MAX function will only return the highest value. So in case above it would return 8 instead of 11.

Answer (score 0):

Select cell A3 and set the formula to `=A1+A2`.  Then click the square in the lower-right corner of the selected cell and drag to D3.  This gives:

```
   |A  B  C  D
---------------
1  |2  8  6  3
2  |1  2  5  2
3  |3 10 11  5
```

Now `=MAX(A3:D3)` produces 11.

Comment: The problem is that i don't want to use third row as "storage row". I just want to put/calculate the final number in **one** cell (so in this case only cell A3 would be used to calculate and determine the answer)

Comment: Why not?  If you don't want to use the third row, then you can use another row, for example row 1000, or another sheet, perhaps hidden.

Comment: Otherwise, you could write a macro, since that would not require using any extra cells.

Comment: I meant just additional/another row. I would like to do this using only formula functions.